# In which directory does the Spark store its methods in Linux (EMR)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I need to find the code for where the ofRows() method is stored within an AWS EMR cluster?

Comment: you mean `spark-sql_*.jar`?

Comment: I think so. I'm not sure. I'm looking for where the Spark methods are kept. I'm nit exactly sure what the file name is, but it's probaby that.

Comment: `/usr/lib/spark/` I guess if you r looking for jars.